# spring/thymeleaf i18n for database content

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, locale, thymeleaf

I have to localize the existing application written in **thymeleaf** and **spring 4**. 
For static content the creation of messages_FR.properties and messages_ES.properties and traditional Spring i18n strategy works well.

The problem comes from dynamic content (stored in the **database** record). 
The previous version of content was displayed by `th:text="${product.title}"`.

Now the database content have been localized by duplicating the fields with lang suffix, so for the table **product** and row **title** I have two additional rows **title_ES** and **title_FR**

and now I need to make this display **local specific**, i.e. for french local it should use `th:text="${product.title_FR}"` or something like `th:text=${@beans.i18n(product.title)}`

What is the recommended way to implement such logic?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what did you mean -  The previous version of content was displayed by th:text="${product.title}" and now I need to make this display local specific. If it's in database what kind of localization are you talking about??

Comment: Sorry, to be not very precise. I updated the post. Yes the **local-specific** data are stored in the DB and I was asking how to implement the **i18n**-related logic in the existing **views**.

Comment: I think you need to extend Thymeleaf with your own Dialect for this sophisticated decision. Suppose it's better to create additional column 'localization' in database and listen localization at level higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several possibilities:

- use your own bean like your `i18n` and use `th:text`. You can use the LocaleContextHolder to access the locale of the request (not fully sure on the name). Your will have full control of how to resolve the keys.
- write a MessagesResolver that resolves keys against the database. Then you use the standard expression for i18n: `#{...}`. You might need to take care of cache eviction as messageresolution is using an internal cache.

Writing your own dialect is not necessary as this is most of the time just to wrap some bean calls in a nicer syntax.

Probably the simplest approach is to use a bean and adapt the text expressions accordingly.
The second approach has the advantage that all messages will be resolvable against the database and you could easily override the values inside the property files at runtime.